# I install gcc5.3.0 on my mac, and I broke it. What should I do to reuse apple-gcc42?

Tags: macos, gcc

I used rm -rf to delete the gcc5.3.0, but mac continues to use gcc5.3.0.
The wrong message:
    g++: error trying to exec 'cc1plus': execvp: No such file or directory

What should I do to reuse apple-gcc42?

Comment: Ddi you try changing the symbolic link?

Comment: I am a green hand, I don't know how to do it. @gsamaras

Comment: Where was GCC 5.3.0 installed?  Where did it come from?  Did you create it or is it from Apple, or one of the auxilliary packagers?  Did your recursive remove actually remove anything?  Does running `xcode-select` help? (Use `man xcode-select` to see what it does; maybe `xcode-select --install` is useful, but I'm not sure since I've never destroyed my compilation system like that.)  Which version of XCode do you have installed?  Which version of Mac OS X are you running?

Comment: GCC5.3.0 is installed at /usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0. I removed the folder gcc.  My Xcode and Mac OS X both are latest. @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Be precise; latest today means Mac OS X 10.11.6 and XCode 7.3.0.  Removing `/usr/local/lib/libexec/gcc` didn't remove the executables from `/usr/local/bin`, so when you run `g++`, the shell is still finding the executable `/usr/local/bin/g++`, but that is not finding its auxilliary programs because you did manage to remove them. You also haven't cleaned up the headers that were installed under `/usr/local/include`, etc. Don't use `rm -fr`; it is crude and only partially effective when you have to uninstall complex suites of software like GCC. You could also use `/usr/bin/g++` instead of `g++`.

Comment: My Mac OS X is 10.11.6 and my Xcode is 7.3.1. So what should I do now?@JonathanLeffler

Comment: Intriguing: I get `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)` from `/usr/bin/g++`.  However, that's not too critical (for you — I'm wondering how I missed an update to XCode … XCode UI says `Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)`; I'm OK).  You need to finish the removal job — remove `gcc` and `g++` from `/usr/local/bin` at minimum.  That should leave you with `/usr/bin/gcc` or `/usr/bin/g++` as the compilers.  You might have to run `hash -r` or start a new terminal window to avoid Bash's caching of the location of the compiler (but you'd get `bash: g++ not found` or something similar as an error message).

Comment: Thank you. This works for me! @JonathanLeffler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Editing comments and responses into an answer.*</sup>

Where was GCC 5.3.0 installed? Where did it come from? Did you create it or is it from Apple, or one of the auxilliary packagers? Did your recursive remove actually remove anything? Does running `xcode-select` help? (Use `man xcode-select` to see what it does; maybe `xcode-select --install` is useful, but I'm not sure since I've never destroyed my compilation system like that.) Which version of XCode do you have installed? Which version of Mac OS X are you running?

> GCC5.3.0 is installed at `/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.3.0`. I removed the folder `gcc`. My Mac OS X is 10.11.6 and my Xcode is 7.3.1.

Removing `/usr/local/lib/libexec/gcc` didn't remove the executables from `/usr/local/bin`, so when you run `g++`, the shell is still finding the executable `/usr/local/bin/g++`, but that is not finding its auxilliary programs because you did manage to remove them. You also haven't cleaned up the headers that were installed under `/usr/local/include`, etc. Don't use `rm -fr`; it is crude and only partially effective when you have to uninstall complex suites of software like GCC. You could also use `/usr/bin/g++` instead of `g++`.

> So what should I do now?

You need to finish the removal job — remove `gcc` and `g++` from `/usr/local/bin` at minimum. That should leave you with `/usr/bin/gcc` and `/usr/bin/g++` as the compilers. You might have to run `hash -r` or start a new terminal window to avoid Bash's caching of the location of the compiler (but you'd get `bash: /usr/local/bin/g++ not found` or something similar as an error message).

> Thank you. This works for me!